# Replacement for CharInSet function in Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi, enums, include, set, delphi-prism

Is there a similar function as CharInSet in Delphi Prism? If not, how would you do it?

I looked online and on StackOverflow, but they speak in terms of Delphi not Delphi Prism for .NET.

I also found out that the include method for setting an element to a set is not available either.

what are the replacements, if any, for these method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to test membership. Use the `+` operator in place of `Include`. A method like `Include` could not exist in Prism since sets are immutable in Prism.

See [here](http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Sets) for full details.

Comment: @ David - Oh good. I have been doing exactly what you said in your answer. I was just wondering if there were any other options. Thanks.

Comment: Heh, in Delphi, `CharInSet()` is actually the replacement for `in`, since Delphi sets can only contain ordinal values up to and including 255.

Comment: Prism is on .NET, and there, "characters" were always Unicode. I have no idea how in Prism, Pascal-like sets are realized, but I bet not the same way as in Pascal.